# Call webmethod in ascx page using jquery ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, webmethod, ascx

For some reasons i want to call webmethod in ascx page from jquery ajax.

.ascx page

```
function StartProcessing() {
    ShowProgress();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ImportExcel.ascx/btnProcessing_Click",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert('hi');

        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
}
```

My webmethod in ascx.cs page:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static void btnProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //code which processes records in excel file
    }
```

Please suggest some way to call webmethod in ascx from jquery ajax

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your method must be static like so:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void ProcessExcelRecords()
{
   //code which processes records in excel file
}
```

Comment: Mark, i have edited my web method, but i need to call it from jquery ajax.